# When checking in code using ahnk to Visual Studio should I check in empty obj and bin folders?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I am checking code for a Visual Studio project into source control.  Is it a best practice to check in empty bin and obj folders or should I let the IDE create them for everyone?  I imagine the answer could be it doesn't matter but I was wondering if one choice over the the other has some advantage I cannot see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `obj` and `bin` folders, I prefer to add them to the ignore list for that directory. That way, they and their contents don't show up if you select the option to "show unversioned files", and no one would be confused about the need to `add` them or the contents.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be not to check-in bin and obj folders, the reason is that these are created by Visual Studio anyway and could give problems when several developers compile the project at the same time, specially, if your source control system doesn't support multiple checkouts at the same time.